# Accessing input control of type file in code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

Using an asp.net fileupload string in an Server Side onClick event.

**ASP.Net file upload control**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="btnFileUpload" runat="server" Width="0px" onchange="this.form.lblUploadStatus.value=GetFileName(this.value);"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUploadStatus" runat="server" Width="680px"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function GetFileName(val) {
    var i = val.lastIndexOf("\\");
    $get('<%= txtUploadStatus.ClientID %>').value = val;
    return true;
}

</script>
```

**.net**

```
using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(CKS_app_settings.sql_conn_string_db))
        {
            try
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, dbConnection);
                //command.Transaction = tn;
                command.CommandText = sSQL;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandTimeout = 1024;

                // Split entire file path to grab filename
                string[] split = txtUploadStatus.Text.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                string fileName = split[06];

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_filename", fileName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_url", txtUrl.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_Title", txtImgTitle.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_alt_text", txtAlt.Text);
                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
               // throw ex;

                //If it failed for whatever reason, rollback the //transaction
                //tn.Rollback();                          
                //No need to throw because we are at a top level call and //nothing is handling exceptions
                result = ex.InnerException.Message;
            }
        }
```

Maybe there was a better solution but this worked for me in the end because I want to insert data into the database and using system.io to write new file to path in one click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpPostedFile file = File1.PostedFile;
string sName = file.FileName; // Contains file name
```

Comment: I tried this and I recieved a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception. Is there an object I have to construct first?

Comment: @nickgowdy, let me guess - your FileUpload control is nested within an UpdatePanel?

Comment: My FileUpload isn't nested between an update panel but I am using one on that page. I have updated my original post to show entire markup of page if that helps.

Comment: Can you try using <asp:FileUpload ID="File1" runat="server" /> instead of your <input /> ?

Comment: Wow I didn't actually know that there was an asp.net file upload control. That makes my life alot easier. Thanks!!

Comment: Hey I am still having some problems now that I am using an asp.net fileupload control. I have been playing around with the code and when I use: "if(fileuploadctrl.hasfile)" it always returns false. I wrote this line of code in the onInit and when I close the page the if statement returns as true.

Comment: What happens if you move it to a different place rather than the OnInit? I'm not sure that control gets rendered that soon.

Comment: Initially I placed it in an onclick event because I want the filepath associated with the fileupload control to be inserted into the database. Using a breakpoint fileuploadctrl.hasfile always would equal to false. I should also point out that the button that I click is in an update panel but the fileupload control is outside the update panel.

Comment: In the end I decided to use javascript to grab the string from my asp.net fileupload control and pass it to a textbox. I figured that I can grab it from the DOM on the client rather than trying to access the string inside an onClick event server side. Then it was just a matter of assigning that string to an sql command object which I used to write the string to the database. I will mark this as the correct answer because using an asp.net file upload control gives me access to some very useful object properties for validating the file before writing it to the path. Thanks again!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6462/discussion-between-nick-gowdy-and-shai)

Answer (score 0):

```
File1.PostedFile.FileName
```

will give you filename

Please follow example of it

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0080__HTML-Controls/inputtypefile.htm

Comment: I tried this and the problem isn't how to access it but there being no value when the onclick event fires in my code.